# Swagger sort Schema Definitions

Tags: swagger, swashbuckle

It is [not possible to create subgroups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/swagger-swaggersocket/z2NO7-qy2b0) in the Swagger documentation.
Further, there is no possibility to sort the models ([A](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/6926), [B](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/7326)).

For the operations, it is possible to work around it using [tags](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/grouping-operations-with-tags/).
Is there a similar solution for the [Data Definitions](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/)?

(We are using Swashbuckle to create an HTML description.)

Comment: I've had a lot of luck with using NSwag (built on top of Swashbuckle) for manipulating the API spec the way you are wanting.  Specifically using the DocumentProcessor (which makes the entire spec document into a manageable object, section by section).  With the DocumentProcessor you could probably pull out each schema definition into an array, sort them, then insert them back in to the spec.  This of course would happen during Startup (.cs)  so that it renders that way on your Swagger page.