# Sorting the Schemas portion of a Swagger page using Swashbuckle

Tags: swagger, swashbuckle, swashbuckle.examples

On my Swagger page, I am (mostly) able to order the operations [as described](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#change-operation-sort-order-eg-for-ui-sorting) on the Swashbuckle page.

Below the operations is a "Schemas" section showing the data structures used by the actions. These data structures appear in a arbitrary order. I would like to sort them.

The question [Swagger sort Schema Defintions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57057487/swagger-sort-schema-definitions) superficially looks like the same question, but in that question "sort" is used in the sense of "sorting the items into different bins", not "ordering a list" which is what I want.

I have made a [document filter](https://github.com/TimothyByrd/swashbuckle_stuff/blob/master/SortDataSchemasDocumentFilter.cs) that "works", but when I look at the code I wrote, I die a little inside.

Is there a more correct way to do this?

Edit: To be specific, what I object to about this code is that it is "working" by sorting the entries in a Dictionary, which is just bad ( see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453190) ).

Turns out the answer was simply to use a SortedDictionary:

```
        openApiDoc.Components.Schemas = new System.Collections.Generic.SortedDictionary<string, OpenApiSchema>(openApiDoc.Components.Schemas);
```

Comment: Why does that order matter to you? swagger-ui has a filter if you want to see something use that: http://swagger-net-test.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index?filter=Res

Comment: Went to that page. The filter does not filter the "Models" part of the page. The Models section shows the models in the order ScopeResponseModel, Location, Arrays, Data, ... basically a random order. And I think that it is not unreasonable to want to sort a list of items.

Comment: Ohh I see, I never even expand that section ... will try that on my end ... I did noticed that you are on `OpenApiDocument` I wonder if that makes a difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you were on the right track with the document filter!

In Startup.cs, `ConfigureServices` method:-

```cs
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    // ...

    // For our document filtering needs.
    c.DocumentFilter<DocumentFilter>();
});
```

And here is the document filter implementation:-

```cs
using System.Linq;

public class DocumentFilter : IDocumentFilter
{
    public DocumentFilter()
    {
    }

    // Implements IDocumentFilter.Apply().
    public void Apply(OpenApiDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
    {
        if (swaggerDoc == null)
            return;

        // Re-order the schemas alphabetically.
        swaggerDoc.Components.Schemas = swaggerDoc.Components.Schemas.OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Key, StringComparer.InvariantCulture)
            .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
    }
}
```

`when I look at the code I wrote, I die a little inside` - embrace the glory of LINQ, and you will be proud of your code!

Comment: The linq code looks nicer, but it is still doing a sort on the dictionary entries.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer, because you inspired me to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

This wouldn't change the final display order for me, but  [MikeBeaton's suggestion whilst reporting a Sort Schema Issue on GitHub](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1844#issue-712104190) worked like a charm..

```
app.UseSwagger(c =>
{
    c.PreSerializeFilters.Add((swagger, _) =>
    {
        if (swagger.Components != null && swagger.Components.Schemas != null)
        {
            var replacement = new Dictionary<string, OpenApiSchema>();
            foreach (var kv in swagger.Components.Schemas.OrderBy(p => p.Key))
            {
                replacement.Add(kv.Key, kv.Value);
            }
            swagger.Components.Schemas = replacement;
        }
    });
})
```